# Using Canvas fillText() - HTML5, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plugin that will fill text based on an image using the following:

```
function draw() {
        //grab font to use
        var fFamily = $(".activeText a .fontType-cont").val();
        ctx.font = startFontSize + 'px ' + fFamily;
        ctx.fillText(text, 10, 100);

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 20, 500, 100);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById(current),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
img = document.createElement('img');
//draw it
img.onload = draw;

img.src = $(".activeGColor").find('img').attr('src');
```

What happens is that the canvas will take that image, display it in the canvas and as the text gets bigger, you see it as the fill for the text.  My issue is that, How can I make it so it does not look stretched or whatnot?  Do I have an option to do so?

What are your ideas?

Comment: Are you increasing the size of the canvas with css, because that generally will not work well

Comment: No I am not.  I just leave it blank and let the image it uses make the size of Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see an example of whats going on here. Your question makes it sound like you have some sort of animation going on... that changes the font-size to a larger and larger size. The way things work by default, is that the text will render proportionally. However if your using any thing like ctx.scale() you obviously could throw that off. Also if your not clearing your canvas each frame, you could get more of a bleed effect, that you may be describing as stretching.

Comment: I don't think I can remake it :/  Here, So when using the .fillText to will text with an image the image is in the background of the text, how could I make it so that the text would see the image that is filling it from far away so it does not look like it is stretched?

Comment: You notice how your text is filled with red, replace that with and image and keep it from sizing so it looks stretched out, is there a way to do so?

Comment: what you really want is to create a clipping path, but you simply cant do that with filltext(), as far as i know.

Comment: How would I go about creating a clipping path?

Comment: You have draw a path, using ctx.beginPath(); ...all your path calls... ctx.closePath();  ctx.clip();... but you'll have to turn your text into a series of lineTo/moveTo calls... its going to be a lot for text. tutorial site: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-vector-masks-using-the-html5-canvas

Comment: Its not, however you can get that effect in webkit browsers using some css...http://jsfiddle.net/bH4tw/2/ but thats only in webkit (chrome/safari). Not much of a canvas thing at this point.